# Geotools Feature Tutorial ClassFormatError

Tags: geotools, classformaterror

I tried to work through the [Feature Tutorial](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html) of geotools. Everything worked well until I got to the code where the Features should be stored in a shapefile:

```
if (featureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
            SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;
            
            // List Features into Collection
            SimpleFeatureCollection collection = new ListFeatureCollection(TYPE, features);
            featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
            try {
                featureStore.addFeatures(collection);
                transaction.commit();
            }catch (Exception problem) {
                problem.printStackTrace();
                transaction.rollback();
            }finally {
                transaction.close();
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }else {
            System.out.println(typeName + "does not support read/write access.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

The runtime exception links to the row "featureStore.addFeatures(collection);
This is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal constant pool index 0 for method name in class file org/geotools/geometry/jts/JTS
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureImpl.getBounds(SimpleFeatureImpl.java:258)
at org.geotools.data.Diff.addToSpatialIndex(Diff.java:201)
at org.geotools.data.Diff.add(Diff.java:195)
at org.geotools.data.store.DiffContentFeatureWriter.write(DiffContentFeatureWriter.java:168)
at org.geotools.data.InProcessLockingManager$1.write(InProcessLockingManager.java:296)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureStore.addFeature(ContentFeatureStore.java:302)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureStore.addFeatures(ContentFeatureStore.java:254)
at de.topotools.topograph.Csv2Shape.main(Csv2Shape.java:121)
```

I updated the maven project and checked if the code is equal to the tutorial's code, but nothing helped. I could also not find any description of this error in relation to geotools searching the internet.

I'm using Java 14.0.2.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please add the version of the code and JVM you are using and check the mvn dependancy:tree output, it should contain `org.locationtech.jts:jts-core:jar:1.17.1:compile`

Comment: This row was missing in the mvn dependancy:tree output. So I checked the pom file and changed the geotools version to 24-shapshot and updated the project. Now i find the entry org.locantiontech.jts.... and everything works fine. I was confused aboud this error, because it previously worked well and the error occured without me changing the pom-file. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your project is missing a jar or two. Also GeoTools doesn't really support any JVMs except 1.8 and 11, but always happy to hear it works in another versions.